# Chopping up a list into a list of lists

Tags: list, scala, immutability

Suppose I have a list of elements `myl` and a function `f`. I would like to chop up `myl` into a list of lists, where each new "sublist" contains a contiguous stretch of `myl` on which the value of `f` is constant.

For example, if `myl = List( (1,2), (3,2), (4,1), (6,2) )` and `def f(x: (Int, Int)) = x._2`. Then the result should be `List( List((1,2), (3,2)), List((4, 1)), List((6,2)) )`.

Is there an elegant way to write such a function without any `var`s?

Comment: "elegant way to write such a function without any vars" - rephrasing that in standard terms, I believe you imply _functional_ instead of _imperative_ way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def groupBy[A](as: List[A])(p: (A, A) => Boolean): List[List[A]] =
  as.foldRight(List.empty[List[A]]) {
    case (x, (ys @ y :: _) :: zs) if p(x, y) => (x :: ys) :: zs
    case (x, ys) => List(x) :: ys
  }
```

---

```
scala> groupBy(myl)(_._2 == _._2)
res0: List[List[(Int, Int)]] = List(List((1,2), (3,2)), List((4,1)), List((6,2)))
```

---

Edit: I also wrote this version, using `span`:

```
def groupBy[A](as: List[A])(p: (A, A) => Boolean): List[List[A]] =
  as match {
    case x :: xs =>
      val (ys, zs) = xs.span(p(x, _))
      (x :: ys) :: groupBy(zs)(p)
    case _ => Nil
  }
```

This is essentially similar to ghik's solution, but using pattern matching instead of `isEmpty` and `head`.

(An explanation of the name `groupBy`: there is a function of the same name in the Haskell library, which has this exact same behaviour.)

Comment: Now that is what I call elegant :) Thanks, I really need to learn more about folding.

Answer (score 2):

Little more general solution:

```
def partitionBy[A](list: List[A])(groupingFunc: A => Any): List[List[A]] =
  if (list.nonEmpty) {
    val firstGroupingValue = groupingFunc(list.head)
    val (group, rest) = list.span(groupingFunc(_) == firstGroupingValue)
    group :: partitionBy(rest)(groupingFunc)
  } else Nil
```

Example usage:

```
scala> partitionBy(List((1,2),(3,2),(5,2),(1,1),(2,1),(3,2),(5,2)))(_._2)
res14: List[List[(Int, Int)]] = List(List((1,2), (3,2), (5,2)), List((1,1), (2,1)), List((3,2), (5,2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `foldRight`

```
val result2 = l.foldRight(List[List[(Int, Int)]]()) {
  (x, acc) =>
    if (acc.isEmpty) {
      List(x) :: Nil
    } else if (acc.head.head._2 == x._2) {
      (x :: acc.head) :: acc.tail
    } else {
      List(x) :: acc
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is too specific for there to exist a general function solving it, so we'll have to write a function of our own.

The standard strategy to implementing functional algorithms is [**Divide and conquer**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm), which basically means extracting the smallest part of the problem and then gradually building up the algorithm over it.

### Implementation

Okay, the obviously smallest thing we'll need is to test two items for contiguity:

```
def testContiguity( a : (Int, Int), b : (Int, Int) ) : Boolean 
  = a._2 == b._2
```

Then we'll need some function arranging the lists using the two-item comparison function. Would be nice if the standard library had it, but it doesn't, so we define our own:

```
def arrange
  [ A ]
  ( list : List[ A ] )
  ( f : (A, A) => Boolean ) 
  : List[ List[ A ] ]
  = list match {
      case a :: b :: tail => 
        if( f(a, b) ) putInFirstGroup( a, arrange( b :: tail )( f ) )
        else putInNewGroup( a, arrange( b :: tail )( f ) )
      case a :: Nil =>
        putInNewGroup( a, Nil )
      case Nil =>
        Nil
    }
```

Okay, you can see that the above implementation relies on two other functions, let's define them too:

```
def putInFirstGroup
  [ A ]
  ( item : A, groups : List[ List[ A ] ] ) 
  : List[ List[ A ] ]
  = groups match {
      case group :: tail =>
        (item :: group) :: tail
      case Nil => 
        (item :: Nil) :: Nil
    }

def putInNewGroup
  [ A ]
  ( item : A, groups : List[ List[ A ] ] ) 
  : List[ List[ A ] ]
  = (item :: Nil) :: groups
```

That's it!

### Usage

```
scala> arrange( List( (1,2), (3,2), (4, 1), (6,2) ) )( testContiguity )
res2: List[List[(Int, Int)]] = List(List((1,2), (3,2)), List((4,1)), List((6,2)))
```

You can now see that we've created a pretty flexible and general solution, working on lists of items of any type and allowing you to use any other testing function to arrange them. Also we've heavily utilized division of a complex algorithm to small easily understandable parts to solve this.